# How to display filtered data in asp.net using linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

I have to display data from a table on a gridview in an asp.net webform application. When the page loads, it should show a 30 day worth of data based upon the createddate field in the table. Above the grid, I have two date picker controls, which can be used to select a date range; when a date range is selected, it should show data based upon the dates. I am restricted to use only linq-to-sql for data access. One option is to select all data from the table, when the page loads, then display 30 day's worth of data.  Filter the data if date range is selected, subsequent to page load. However the problem is that it may bring too much data. Please let me know a better option.

Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter in the database - which is basically how most of Linq-to-SQL will work anyway. You just need to write the where clause using your date range.